# get bad data in group by and min mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, group-by

Im trying to get the older person in a team, im using the group by and min operators, but it not return me the correct values.

This is my example data:

table persons:

```
id   |  name   |  birthdate           |  team_id
-----------------------------------------
1    | person1 |  1993-09-29 15:15:15 | 1
2    | person2 |  1994-09-29 15:15:15 | 1
3    | person3 |  1992-09-29 15:15:15 | 2
4    | person4 |  1990-09-29 15:15:15 | 2
```

im using this query to get the older person by team:

```
select id, name, min(birthdate) from persons group by team_id
```

im expected the query return me this data:

```
id   |  name   |  min(birthdate)  
----------------------------
1    | person1 |  1993-09-29 15:15:15
4    | person4 |  1990-09-29 15:15:15
```

but it is returning this:

```
id   |  name   |  min(birthdate)
----------------------------
1    | person1 |  1993-09-29 15:15:15
3    | person3 |  1990-09-29 15:15:15
```

the birthdate is correctly returned, but the name and id are incorrect.

What is happening here? What is my error?

Answer (score 1):

This works on every mysql Version.

But you didn't specify what should happen  if two have the same birthday.

The second result shows you what happens with my query.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE persons (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `name` VARCHAR(7),
>   `birthdate` datetime,
>   `team_id` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO persons
>   (`id`, `name`, `birthdate`, `team_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'person1', '1993-09-29 15:15:15', '1'),
>   ('2', 'person2', '1994-09-29 15:15:15', '1'),
>   ('3', 'person3', '1992-09-29 15:15:15', '2'),
>   ('4', 'person4', '1990-09-29 15:15:15', '2');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> p.`id`, p.`name`, p.`birthdate`#
> FROM
> persons p INNER JOIN
> (select team_id, min(birthdate) minbirth from persons group by team_id) mint 
> ON p.birthdate = mint.minbirth AND p.team_id = mint.team_id
> ORDER By p.team_id,p.`id`
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name    | birthdate          
> -: | :------ | :------------------
>  1 | person1 | 1993-09-29 15:15:15
>  4 | person4 | 1990-09-29 15:15:15
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO persons
>   (`id`, `name`, `birthdate`, `team_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('5', 'person5', '1993-09-29 15:15:15', '1'),
>   ('6', 'person6', '1990-09-29 15:15:15', '2');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> p.`id`, p.`name`, p.`birthdate`#
> FROM
> persons p INNER JOIN
> (select team_id, min(birthdate) minbirth from persons group by team_id) mint 
> ON p.birthdate = mint.minbirth AND p.team_id = mint.team_id
> ORDER By p.team_id,p.`id`
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name    | birthdate          
> -: | :------ | :------------------
>  1 | person1 | 1993-09-29 15:15:15
>  5 | person5 | 1993-09-29 15:15:15
>  4 | person4 | 1990-09-29 15:15:15
>  6 | person6 | 1990-09-29 15:15:15
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1068abdf1023fea1d5b764cfafa46d9f)*

Answer (score 0):

This is not an aggregation query.  It is a *filtering* query.  I recommend a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select p.*  -- you can select only the columns you want
from persons p
where p.birthdate = (select min(p2.birthdate)
                     from persons p2
                     where p2.team_id = p.team_id
                    );
```

Another very common approach is to use window functions:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             rank() over (partition by team_id order by birthdate) as seqnum
      from persons p
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```